# Get all users from Azure AD using Graph Api Only Top 100 Records are getting Recieved

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, blazor

```
@inject GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient


public static async Task<List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.User>> GetUserListAsync()
    {
        //type 1 only getting 100 records
        var azureUsersList = graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();

        Microsoft.Graph.Models.UserCollectionResponse? userCollectionResponse = 
            await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync();

        List<Microsoft.Graph.Models.User> userList = new();

        PageIterator<Microsoft.Graph.Models.User, UserCollectionResponse> pageIterator =
            PageIterator<Microsoft.Graph.Models.User, 
                 UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(
                graphServiceClient, userCollectionResponse,
                user => { userList.Add(user); return true; });

        await pageIterator.IterateAsync();

        return userList;
    }
```

i need to get all the users in my organisation and show it in dropdown i got only 100 records while using the first type, so i am trying to implement int the above type but facing

The type or namespace name 'graphServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

kindly provide a sample method to be used in blazor server

thanks in advance

Comment: 100 items per request is  expected behavior, and using PageIterator is required if we want to have all records.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the using clause? Just like you see, if I comment my using clause, I would get this error.

[image]

Here's what I test in my side:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using BlazorServerGraph5.Data
@using Microsoft.Graph
@using Microsoft.Graph.Models
@inject GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync(requestOption=>
        {
            requestOption.QueryParameters.Top = 1;    
        
        });

        var userList = new List<User>();
        var pageIterator = PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>
            .CreatePageIterator(
                graphServiceClient, users,
                // Callback executed for each item in
                // the collection
                (user) =>
                {
                    var name = user.DisplayName;
                    userList.Add(user);
                    return true;
                });
        await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
    }
}


using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
    
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.13" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.13" NoWarn="NU1605" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.40.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.1.6" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.16.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.16.1" />
  <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="2.16.1" />  this is for Microsoft.Graph V4.X-->
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.16.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]